# How do I make an embedable button with lightbox? (similar to addthis)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Have you seen the embed code of "AddThis"? It's like this:

```
                <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style" >
                    <ul id="social-icons">
                        <li><a class="addthis_button_facebook"  style="padding:0px !important"></a></li>
                        <li><a class="addthis_button_twitter"  style="padding:0px !important"></a></li>
                        <li><a class="addthis_button_linkedin"  style="padding:0px !important"></a></li>
                        <li><a class="addthis_button_email"  style="padding:0px !important"></a></li>
                        <li><a class="addthis_button_compact"  style="padding:0px !important"></a></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_clickback":true};</script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4e1db3944c85634b"></script>
```

I'm curious, how does it work and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I've not come across it before but I would guess judging by the code you provided that the addthis_button class pads out an area and uses a css background to form an "icon". The JavaScript library at the end obvious adds all the magic by binding/adding click events to the "icons"

Not strictly related but there is no need for "!important" in  the style attribute because inline styles always takes preference.

Comment: yeah, that's what I've been trying to find out..how could I possibly do the same action. It definitely uses AJAX, but how? >.<

Comment: While depends on the js code. Which aspect are you trying to find out the presentation (i.e making the <a> look like icons) or adding clicks to <a> or doing the ajax calls?